# Vue-Auth issue in setting token to header['authorization']

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue in setting the authorization token to the request header. I always get a 401 Unathuroized issue after setting my header using a bearer driver. Below is my code:

> bearer.js

```js
module.exports = {
 request: function (req, token) {
  this.options.http._setHeaders.call(this, req, {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token})
 },

 response: function (res) {
  if (res.data.token) {
   return res.data.token
  }
 }
}
```

> main.js

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios' 
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

import VueAuth from '@websanova/vue-auth'
Vue.use(VueAuth, {
 auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer.js'),
   http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
   router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
 refreshData: {url: 'auth/refresh', method: 'GET', enabled: false, interval: 30},
 fetchData: {url: 'auth/user', method: 'GET', enabled: false},
 notFoundRedirect: {path: '/admin'},
 rolesVar: 'roles',
})
```

and the code in login.vue

```js
this.$auth.login({
                data: credentials,
                url: process.env.VUE_APP_URL + '/api/v1/login',
                fetchUser: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.data){
                        localStorage.setItem('user',(JSON.stringify(response.data.data)));
                        this.$auth.user(response.data.data);
                        this.$auth.watch.authenticated = true;
                        this.$auth.watch.loaded = true;
                        this.$router.push('/dashboard');
                        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + response.data.data.token;
                        debugger;
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    this.$notify({
                        type: 'warn',
                        title: 'Login',
                        text: 'Login failed'
                    });                  
                },          
            })
```

I tried to add a debugger inside the request method of a bearer.js driver, that doesn't seem to execute.

Comment: Print the token fetched from this line `axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + response.data.data.token` and verify it into [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) or use it with manual request with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or similar sw.

Comment: When I print that line (header with the token) and use manually in postman it works, but from the bearer driver, it is not set globally for all the requests. Is there anything am I missing in the setup?

I have followed the Doc as it is.

Comment: 1. in the the docs: _Before using $auth the app should make sure it has been properly loaded first by using $auth.ready()._ 2. The [`bearer.js`](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/blob/master/drivers/auth/bearer.js) from docs is little different from yours. 3. Can you complete the authentication to the provider and redirect back to you site ?  [Reference](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/blob/master/docs/StepByStepGuide.md)

Comment: maybe you need "axios.defaults.withCredentials = true" in main.js?